# AngularJS: ng-repeat is listing thousands of elements when there should be none

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've searched for issues similar to this but have found none. I have a service which does a $http get for a list of items, and a controller which calls that service and binds the list to $scope. On my page I use ng-repeat to list the items but for some strange reason it's listing 2473 items, even though there's none in the database.

service.js

```
getTickits : function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/api/tickits').success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);     
        })
        .error(function(data){
            deferred.reject(data);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

controller.js

```
$scope.tickits = [];

$scope.getTickits = function(){
    TickitService.getTickits().then(function (data) {
        $scope.tickits = data;
    })
}

$scope.getTickits();
```

Then on my page:

```
<div id = "tickit-list" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="tickit in tickits track by $index">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Title: {{ tickit.title }}</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Description: {{ tickit.description }}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteTickit(tickit._id)">Delete tickit</a>
            </div>

        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason I added 'track by $index' is because without that I get an error on the chrome console saying 'Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys'.

I really don't know how it thinks there are over 2 thousand items so if anyone has any ideas it would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: What do your developer tools tell you about the response of the api call? Press F12 and check the network tab for the calls to `/api/tickits`

Comment: The status code is: 304 Not Modified.

Comment: And the response content?

Comment: Is it the response headers? 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Wed, 15 Apr 2015 09:48:13 GMT
ETag:W/"9a9-3299437464"
X-Powered-By:Express

Comment: Under the response tab, the content is the html for my index template.

Comment: If you are using Chrome: F12 => In network tab, click on the api call. On the right hand side you will see additional tabs, one of them is called "Response". It will show you the response content of your api call

Comment: I don't understand your latest comment. From your description I expected the api response to be some array like `["tickit1", "tickit2", ...]` and not an HTML template

Comment: Yeah I just noticed the response tab after adding my previous comment. As I say it's the index.html template i'm using where I just have some nav links, then an ng view where my partials get injected.

Comment: u get 304 status for ajax call?

Comment: I just tested my api/tickits endpoint with POSTMAN and it returns the index.html also. Seems my issues isn't Angular related and must be something to do with the server side code! I'll redirect my attention there and try to fix it. Thanks for the responses guys.